# Titanium Build Project returns: Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

i am new in titanium development environment, i have just installed titanium, nodejs and android framework on my pc. everything is fine but when i am trying to run my project it's giving me this log :-

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.1, Titanium SDK version 3.2.2.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[INFO] :   Deploy type: development
[INFO] :   Building for target: emulator
[INFO] :   Building for emulator: Nexus 7
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK: 19
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: C:\Users\adnig\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.2.GA\android\dev_keystore (tidev)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: C:\Users\adnig\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Work\build\android\build-manifest.json does not exist
[INFO] :   Launching emulator: Nexus 7
[INFO] :   Running: C:\Users\adnig\Downloads\Compressed\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\tools\emulator.exe "-avd" "Nexus 7" "-port" "5554" "-no-boot-anim" "-partition-size" "128"
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

i don't know what's this problem is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you installed required Android SDKs.

In your case you need to install Android SDK 19 or change it in `tiapp.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Titanium , the `" Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1 "` error is the most common error and it does not point to something specific. Basically everything that makes your app / emulator crash or close will throw up that error. Common errors that cause this are :

-A faulty setup of the SDK

-An error in your Code

-Mismatch between The titanium IDE version in your `tiapp.xml` file and your actual titanium version.

-An error in your emulator

Also note that the default emulator is too slow.

What I would do in your situation :
-Check the status of your SDK by going to `Dashboard`, and scroll down to `setup native sdk's.` Make sure that the environment you are deploying to is shown as green !

-Use a real device to test, or use `genymotion` as emulator (it's super fast !)

-Set up a new project (`file -> new project -> mobile application project -> 2 tabbed alloy , fill in the details`) with sample code and see if it runs.